# Ruby on Rails: odd stylesheet issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, webrick

When I open up a page that's using my CSS it will work once, but won't work again until you open up the CSS and re-save it. Every other time I try to *directly* access my CSS, it works fine. But the other times, it doesn't work and I receive this server output:

```
[2010-08-01 12:49:37] ERROR NoMethodError: private method `gsub!' called for #<Class:0x7f6d0639ad80>
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/htmlutils.rb:16:in `escape'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:232:in `set_error'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:94:in `handle_file'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:73:in `service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/railties/lib/webrick_server.rb:60:in `dispatch'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    /var/www/rails-blog/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2010:12:49:37 BST] "GET /stylesheets/scaffold.css HTTP/1.1" 500 343
- -> /stylesheets/scaffold.css?1280662371
```

The code I'm using to include the stylesheet is `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scaffold' %>`. I've restarted the Ruby server but with no effect. What could be causing this problem?

This is from reading [one of the official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

This does not happen when running Mongrel.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using here?

Comment: @pjmorse: 2.2.3-2 (Ubuntu 10.04).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in WEBrick, see http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206225.

[On 10.06.2010 03:19, Michael Pitman (mcp) posted](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206225#918169):

> To continue using Webrick, instead of
>   switching to Mongrel, you can also 
>   just edit line 15 of
>   lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/htmlutils.rb to
>   read
>
> ```
>   str = string ? string.to_s.dup : ""
> ```
>
> The problem is that NotModified
>   exception is getting passed to 
>   HTMLUtils::escape as a class, rather
>   than a string (originally raised in 
>   HTTPServlet::DefaultFileHandler).
>   Since the only things that can really 
>   be HTML escaped are strings, it should
>   be safe to always convert the  input
>   to string.
>
> I suspect that the potential
>   performance penalty may prevent a
>   solution  like that from making it to
>   the standard ruby library, but it's a
>   simple  workaround.
>
> Alternatively, in the handle_file
>   method of webrick's DispatchServlet 
>   (lib/webrick_server.rb in the rails
>   gem), before it calls res.set_error 
>   with the exception, you could force
>   the err.message to be a string, or 
>   even clear the message, since I think
>   it's discarded anyway for 
>   NotModified.
>
> Michael